# WebRTC Conference Quality using several PeerConnection

Tags: android, webrtc, voip, multipeer-connectivity

Using Peer to Peer call is pretty simple, and deliver clear audio between users. And during some workaround, we created conference with WebRTC source, using several PeerConnections. Maybe it's not the best way to do it, but it's possible and furthermore it's enough for small groups, like 3-4 connections. In our case, every connection goes Ok, but with some specific devices we getting awful Audio Quality. For this example Nexus 6p and Nexus 5 with Android 6.0.

So maybe this very specific question, but it's happens only for this devices, and with Android 6.0. So after updating some device to Android 7.0 solve problem, but it's still wired. We checked connection statistics and everythings looks Ok. No packet lost with network changes, no specific bitrate, etc. Only one difference, what we catch, it's Jitter Buffer value. On other devices, where we have several PeerConnection, we receive around 120 expected and 130 actual. And difference with this value was around 2 - 5. But in case of problematic devices, expected Jitter is 20 and actual 240. Using Opus codec on all sides, and sample bitrate from SDP settings.

I still doesn't know main reason, and calculation Jitter Buffer, it's just surmise. **So yes, maybe there are another ways to do conference?** Or what is the strange behavior using several PeerConnection. Because conference quality still bad, and we cannot find solution for a long time.  **And, what is the correct way to solve issue above?** I think not only I faced with problem of conference quality, or device specific in this case.

Thanks.